# Mitigating CVE-2016-3115 By Disabling X11Forwarding

Tags: openssh, sshd, x11-forwarding

I want to mitigate [CVE-2016-3115](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-3115). The [report from OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/txt/x11fwd.adv) states that the vulnerability exists when X11Forwarding is enabled. It shows as enabled in my  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but I don't know why. It's a server that I only access via SSH (PuTTY) and SFTP. What are the possible issues that could come from disabling X11Forwarding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are accessing server using `ssh` and `PuTTY` and using only command-line utilities, you are good to disable X11 forwarding.

X11 forwarding is needed only if you want to run X11 applications (graphical, window) on the remote server and have them displayed on your local desktop.

Also you didn't specify which Ubuntu version you are using, but currently I don't see in changelog, that this patch was backported even to [15.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily-updates/openssh-server).

Comment: 12.04 LTS. This page doesn't show that it still "needs-triage" http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-3115.html

Comment: Yes. That is the correct place to find it :) Thanks for link. I didn't know that one.  But the fact is that the setup which would allow to exploit this bug is really specific.